# How can I use foreach and fork together to do something in parallel?

Tags: foreach, fork, system-verilog, uvm

This question is not UVM specific but the example that I am working on is UVM related.
I have an array of agents in my UVM environment and I would like to launch a sequence on all of them in parallel.

If I do the below:

```
foreach (env.agt[i])
  begin
    seq.start(env.agt[i].sqr);
  end
```

, the sequence `seq` first executes on `env.agt[0].sqr`. Once that gets over, it then executes on `env.agt[1].sqr` and so on.

I want to implement a foreach-fork statement so that `seq` is executed in parallel on all `agt[i]` sequencers.

No matter how I order the fork-join and foreach, I am not able to achieve that. Can you please help me get that parallel sequence launching behavior?

Thanks.

Update to clarify the problem I am trying to solve:
The outcome of the below code constructs is the exact same as above without the fork-join.

```
foreach (env.agt[i])
  fork
    seq.start(env.agt[i].sqr);
  join
```

```
fork
  foreach (env.agt[i])
    seq.start(env.agt[i].sqr);
  join
```

```
// As per example in § 9.3.2 of IEEE SystemVerilog 2012 standard
for (int i=0; i<`CONST; ++i)
  begin
    fork
      automatic int var_i = i;
      seq.start(env.agt[var_i].sqr);
    join
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Greg's solution below helped me derive the solution to my UVM based problem. Here is my solution:**

The below fork-join block resides in the main_phase task in a test case class. The `wait fork;` statement waits for all the fork statements in its scope (= the foreach_fork begin-end block) to finish before proceeding further. An important thing to note is that the wrapping fork-join around the begin-end was required for setting the scope of `wait fork;` to the foreach_fork block.

```
fork 
  begin : foreach_fork
    seq_class seq **[`CONST]**;
    foreach(env.agt[i])
      begin
        int j = i;
        **seq[j] = seq_class::type_id::create
                  (.name($sformatf("seq_%0d", j)), .contxt(get_full_name()));**
        fork
          begin
            seq[j].start(env.agt[j].sqr);
          end
        join_none // non-blocking thread
      end
    **wait fork;**
  end : foreach_fork  
join
```

Alternative solution that makes use of the in-sequence objection to delay the sim end.

```
begin
  seq_class seq **[`CONST]**;
  foreach(env.agt[i])
    begin
      int j = i;
      **seq[j] = seq_class::type_id::create
                (.name($sformatf("seq_%0d", j)), .contxt(get_full_name()));**
      fork
        begin
          **seq[j].starting_phase = phase;**
          seq[j].start(env.agt[j].sqr);
        end
      join_none // non-blocking thread
    end
end
```

*I realized that I also needed to create a new sequence object for each seq I wanted to run in parallel.*

Thanks to Dave for making the point that the properties in System Verilog classes are automatic by default.

Note for the alternative solution:
As I didn't use `wait fork;` I use the UVM objections raised in the sequence itself to do the job of holding off the simulation `$finish` call. To enable raising of the objections in the sequences, I use the `seq[j].starting_phase = phase;` construct.

Comment: Create a sub-scope to wrap around the `foreach-begin-fork-join_none-end` with a `begin-end`, make sure the "watchdog timer" is not within this sub-scope (Adding additional sub-scopes is okay too; recommend using scope labels). Add the `wait fork` to the end this new sub-scope. The "watchdog timer" will not be part of the sub-scopes `fork wait` monitoring. A `semaphore` is another option but too complected to to explain in a comment.

Comment: Hi Greg, thanks. I had tried that yesterday and due to some mistake that didn't work out. Today I simply put the `wait fork;` before that last `end` and it worked! Now I am sticking with the `wait fork;` solution. :)

Comment: Alright, I figured why creating the begin-end scope didn't work yesterday but worked today. Yesterday I did not have a fork-join wrapping that begin-end. So my understand is that the `wait fork;` treated the first fork-join block around it as the scope. If the `wait fork;` is not inside any fork-join, it waits for ALL fork statements to end.

Answer (score 14):

The issue is each thread of the fork is pointing to the same static variable `i`. Each thread needs its own unique copy and this can be achieved with the `automatic` keyword.

```
foreach (env.agt[i])
  begin
    automatic int var_i = i;
    fork
      seq.start(env.agt[var_i].sqr);
    join_none // non_blocking, allow next operation to start
  end
wait fork;// wait for all forked threads in current scope to end
```

[IEEE std 1800-2012](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2012.html) § 6.21 "Scope and lifetime" gives examples of the uses static and automatic. Also check out § 9.3.2 "Parallel blocks", the last example shows demonstrates parallel threads in a for-loop.

Use `join_none` to create new threads; § 9.3.2 "Parallel blocks", Table 9-1—"fork-join control options".

Use `fork wait` statement to wait for all threads in the current scope to complete; § 9.6.1 "Wait fork statement"

---

Example:

```
byte a[4];
initial begin
    foreach(a[i]) begin
        automatic int j =i;
        fork
            begin
                a[j] = j;
                #($urandom_range(3,1));
                $display("%t :: a[i:%0d]:%h a[j:%0d]:%h",
                        $time, i,a[i], j,a[j]);
            end
        join_none // non-blocking thread
    end
    wait fork; // wait for all forked threads in current scope to end
    $finish;
end
```

Outputs:

> 2 :: a[i:4]:00 a[j:3]:03
>   2 :: a[i:4]:00 a[j:0]:00
>   3 :: a[i:4]:00 a[j:2]:02
>   3 :: a[i:4]:00 a[j:1]:01

Comment: Hi Greg, that didn't make the sequences start in parallel. I referred to § 9.3.2 and tried using for loop instead of foreach, with the fork-join keywords (I can't use fork-join_none in my application as the example shows). But still I see the sequences starting in succession.   I have updated my original post with the example that didn't work either.

Comment: @kaushalmodi didn't realize that `seq.start(...)` was a blocking task method. I have updated my answer with an example.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. The example you posted worked perfectly well. I just needed to do some tweaking to fit my UVM environment.

Comment: BTW, no need for the `automatic` keyword if this code is inside a class method - all variable declarations inside class methods are automatic by default. The reverse is default static outside of a class, to be backward compatible with Verilog.

Answer (score 2):

I think that the more "UVM" way to approach this is with a virtual sequence.  Assuming you already have a virtual sequencer which instantiates an array of agent sequencers then the body your virtual sequence would look something like this:

```
fork
  begin: isolation_thread
    foreach(p_sequencer.agent_sqr[i])
      automatic int j = i;
      fork
        begin
          `uvm_do_on(seq, p_sequencer.agent_sqr[j]);
        end
      join_none
    end
    wait fork;
  end: isolation_thread
join
```

This has worked for me in the past.

Answer (score -2):

try with

```
int i = 0
foreach (env.agt)
  begin
    seq.start(env.agt[i].sqr);
    i++;
end
```

Comment: You did not get the question. The code snippet I posted works; you don't need to manually increment i. The problem is that I can't get the seq.start(env.agt[i].sqr) to happen in parallel whether I put fork-join inside or outside the foreach.